# Android: Only view file stored on server and not download it

Tags: android, android-intent, android-file

My application has a feature to view the file which is stored on server.

Currently, I am using the following code to view the file stored on server:

```
String url = "http://www.google.com";
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
startActivity(i);
```

But this is firstly download the file from the server. and then open the file by using respective application.

But is it possible to view file directly with out downloading?

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Viewing it without downloading is impossible. You could only download parts of it, or download a preview or something, but you have to download somethind. You don't have to store it, though.

Comment: Hi...Thanks for the Response...:)
Yes...I do not want to store file on my device then how can I view it...?

Comment: Without downloading I think its not possible manali, I think there should be some online tools to do it, so just search for it, if any third party library should provide this kind of feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in my comment, viewing a file **requires downloading** it.
What you might mean, is that you don't want to **store** it.

The problem is that the Android intent system doesn't offer this degree of flexibility, which is usually a good thing. You tell it to view a file, and it does that with whatever app it can. And there's no problem with storing it, you have to store it. The problem is *where* you store it. To view it, you have to at least store it in memory, storing it as an Android managed temporary file could also fulfill your need, and what's wrong with just storing it somewhere else and deleting it afterwards?

If you really **need to store it to a custom place** you'll have to leave the intent system and do the downloading yourself.

Comment: Hello...Thanks for the reply.
Exactly...I do not want to store a file on an android device because of some security reasons. Can you please give me code for it?

Comment: Really, there are [numerous](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16723714/how-to-read-and-use-the-content-of-a-website-in-android-app) [examples](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17271147/android-get-content-from-url) [of](http://www.coderzheaven.com/2011/07/17/how-to-read-webpage-contents-as-a-string-in-android/) [this](http://argillander.wordpress.com/2011/11/23/get-web-page-source-code-in-android/) on the internet.

Comment: Hi..Thanks for the response. I got my solution... :)

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
try {  
        URL url = new URL("your url");
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
        String string;
        while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {

        }
        in.close();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
</code>
```

Answer (score 0):

> But is it possible to view file directly with out downloading?

NO, as far as I know. Whenever you want to view the content on the server, those are first downloaded to client. How much data is downloaded at a time, depends on the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

With an intent for "http://www.google.com"; you are not downloading any file. You are not specifying a file either. The default application will contact "http://www.google.com"; and receive some html source. That has nothing to do with a file.